# How does до сих пор mean 'still'

Tags: idioms

Would someone be able to analyze the phrase "до сих пор?"
I know it means "still," but I translate it as "until these then," and I dont understand why it can mean "still."

Comment: Am I correct that сих is genitive plural of сей?

Comment: @N romaai Yes. And _пор_ is gen. pl. of _пора́_ ‘time’. So _до сих пор_ can be literally translated as ‘until this time’. Pretty clear, IMHO.

Comment: BTW, it's more comfortable to refrain from treating phrases like this with word-for-word translations. It's easier to view до сих пор as "a single word" with one meaning than a conglomeration of words that make Russian seem even crazier than it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"До сих пор"** means literally **"till these times"**. Yes, it is the Genitive case plural used with the preposition "до". "Сих" comes from "сии", which used to mean "these", in the modern Russian language it is the pronoun "эти". "Пор" comes from "пора" which means "time, period, season".

Answer (score 2):

In terms of whether it means "still," as a Russian learner myself, I've noticed that there are several ways to express "still" in Russian. 
Here are just the ones I've learned, with their literal translations:

1. (**всё**) **ещё** : *still*
2. **до сих пор** : *up to (and including) now*
3. **по-прежнему**: *as before*